# Apache tomcat gives error "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start." while starting

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Here below is the console output which gives when i trying to start tomcat server:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I belive there is a servlet or something which is getting loaded on start is failing hence the tomcat could not start.

Comment: There is exception in your error log ILLEGALARGUMENTEXCEPTION
balance/working in servlet mapping .Please check your url pattern and mathc that with servlet mapping that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern for servlet mapping is not valid apparently. Following is its specification:

- A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix
  is used for path mapping.
- A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
  mapping.
- A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
  servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
  request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
- All other strings are used for exact matches only.

Answer (score 0):

Some times your local host port already using in other application(ex:skype)

So firstly goto the tomcat server property page and change the port of that and restart the server.

if not work search the application that is already used the port of the tomcat server and kill that process.

If not work all the things try to repair or reinstall the OS.